# Finding the field name on the webpage and check its input type and passing the value

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to achieve the following with a function on the webpage.

1) Find tr with the matching text(This will be the field)
2) Inside the same tr Find its type(could be checkbox, textbox or select dropdown). This will be the enter value field. 
3) Enter the value

This is what I have so far:

```
class pageCommon(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver, field):

        self.driver = driver
        self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[%s]" % field)

    # checkbox type is checkbox
    def click_checkbox(self, checkboxvalue):
        self.row.find_element_by_xpath('./td/input[@type="checkbox"]').click()

    # dropbox type is hidden in the html code
    def select_dropdown(self, dropdownvalue):
        Select(self.row.find_element_by_xpath('./td/input[@type="hidden"]').select_by_visible_text(text)

    def enterText(self, text):
        self.row.find_element_by_xpath('./td/input[@type="checkbox"]').sendkeys("test")
```

1) Here is the HTML code for the checkbox

[image]

[image]

2) Here is the HTML code for the textbox:

[image]

[image]

3) Here is the HTML code for the dropdown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show example of how your element might looks like (`HTML`)

Comment: I have edited my question. pls take a lot

Comment: It's not quite clear what is actually a problem? Did you get any exceptions with your code or just need to make some optimizations?

Comment: i want to make some optimizations if possible and wanted to know if this is the right approach.

Comment: Your `field` values are already defined? Do you want to create class instance like `pageCommon(driver, "checkbox")` or `pageCommon(driver, "textbox")`... and to perform appropriate action with specified webelement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but I can try to describe how to resolve these problems:

1) To find the tr which matches the text you can use the following xpath:

```
//tr[descendant::th[contains(text(),'your_text_here')]]
```

2) To find the input type you will have to locate the input inside the tr which matches the text. After locating the input, get the type attribute from the element. To find the input you can try the following xpath:

```
//tr[descendant::th[contains(text(),'your_text_here')]]//input
```

3) Now you need to enter the value according to each input type.